# How to add fixed price to subtotal of product cart in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, update-subtotal

I want to add fixed price to product subtotal.

**Example:**

If product price = $10, qty = 3 and subtotal = $30.

Now I want to add another $20 to subtotal as setup free.

I tried using **checkout_cart_product_add_after** and **checkout_cart_update_items_after**  observers.

```
$item->setCustomPrice($price);
$item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
$item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
```

but it modifying product  price also. I haven't idea to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to give tier price to product so it will automatically adjust the price of product based on quantity in your cart.

**UPDATED:**

```
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session'); 
    $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    $quote->setSubtotal(0); 
    $quote->setBaseSubtotal(0); 
    $quote->save();
```

Comment: no it not quantity based  it may apply any quantity

Comment: Can you explain more what you want to do?

Comment: I need to modify subtotal price  as example  subtotal +20

Comment: see my modified answer

Comment: is it change each individual product subtotal separatly in cart   for product 1 subtotal+20,

Comment: it will change the complete total of cart not individual.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60877/discussion-between-borncoder-and-srinath-madusanka).